# date minus seconds always returns same

Tags: php, windows, date

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:m:s', strtotime('15 minutes ago')) . "<br/>";
echo date('Y-m-d H:m:s', time()-900) . "<br/>";
echo date('Y-m-d H:m:s', time());
```

I am running WAMPP on Windows 7 and all 3 calls returning same time.

Comment: You're most likely looking for `H:i:s` rather than `H:m:s`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
'H:m:s' should be 'H:i:s'
   ^                 ^
```

Spot the difference

- m = Months
- i = Minutes

Comment: o da**..... thanks... need more coffee...

Answer (score 1):

The error in your code:

'Y-m-d H:m:s'
should be
'Y-m-d H:i:s'

m is month
i is minute

Comment: Both give the same results and are perfectly valid. `strtotime('15 minutes ago')` - `strtotime('-15 minutes')`

Comment: @Fred-ii- My mistake. I was always taught to use '-' instead of ago. But since both work the same I guess it doesn't matter.